# how to add many objects to the same list box item?

Tags: vb.net, object, listbox

I  want to add many objects to the same list box item like images and text boxes(in vb.net). I use `listbox.items.add()` but it adds only one object per item.

Comment: Assuming you are using Windows Forms, the ListBox Control is not the most suitable Control for this purpose. You might consider using the `StackPanel` instead.

Comment: The `DataGrid` is another popular option.

Comment: Thanks for comments , how can i use infinite scrolling in long list selector?

Comment: Have you tried using listbox.items.addrange(). You  pass it a collection of items to add rather than one at a time.